Received http2 header with status: 502
При попытке обратиться к серверу grpc. Выдаёт следующие: Received http2 header with status: 502.
На сервер через docker контейнер запущен nginx, вот nginx.conf:
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

upstream users_service {
  server cj_user-users2-1:50052;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80 http2;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name 92.53.119.150;
    default_type application/grpc;    

    location /users. {
      grpc_pass grpc://users_serivce;
      grpc_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      grpc_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
      grpc_set_header Connection keep-alive;
      grpc_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
      grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}

Если делать запросы на прямую, то всё работает. Помогите пожалуйста


Что в логе ошибок nginx? 2) /users. - почему точка в конце?


nginx: [warn] the "listen ... http2" directive is deprecated, use the "http2" directive instead in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9
46.0.80.31 - - [10/May/2024:11:27:07 +0000] "POST /users.Users/GetUsers HTTP/2.0" 502 157 "-" "grpc-python-asyncio/1.63.0 grpc-c/40.0.0 (osx; chttp2)"
2024/05/10 11:27:07 [error] 22#22: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.0.80.31, server: 92.53.119.150, request: "POST /users.Users/GetUsers HTTP/2.0", upstream: "grpc://127.0.0.1:50052", host: "92.53.119.150:80"

users с (.), потому что в прото файле задан package

Спасите меня пожалуйста)

Ну вам же ясно написано «connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream». Проверяйте что там с вашим приложением и запущено ли оно вообще на этой машине.

И, кстати, если nginx в контейнере, то апстрим должен быть не 127.0.0.1:50052

Да я изменил на название контейнера, проблема осталась

Оно запущено, к нему идут запросы, но почему то имеено через nginx не хочет работать

17ca1f82b851   cj_user-users2   "python src/main.py"     20 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:50052->50051/tcp, :::50052->50051/tcp   cj_user-users2-1

2024-05-10 11:38:54,971 [INFO] (intercept_service) /users.Users/GetUserById

Ну теперь разберитесь почему у вас апстрим  127.0.0.1:50052. Я на 99.99% уверен что внутри контейнера должен быть другой адрес. Потому что 127.0.0.1 это адрес этого же контейнера с nginx и никакого приложения там нет

Так я же вынес именно этот порт, я уже сказал вам, что меня это. Но по итогу у меня заработал один сервис, но теперь вот такая ошибка при запросе ко второму: Temporary failure in name resolution grpc
